# What is this expression and how is this defined in python as i can't use it with lists

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code in Python:

```
import numpy as np
arr = numpy.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]])
print(arr[::-1]) # reverses the array
print(arr[:,::-1] # reverses the array in the second dimension
print(arr[:,:,::-1] # reverses the array in the third dimension,i.e. all elements
print(arr[...,::-1]# gives the same output as above line
```

Output:

```
array([[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]])
array([[[4,5,6],[1,2,3]],[[10,11,12],[7,8,9]]])
array([[[3,2,1],[6,5,4]],[[9,8,7],[12,11,10]]])
array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]])
```

now, i wanna know what is arr[...] as it prints the whole list as it is,but is working in a different way for thefinal print statement.
And, why doesn't the same syntax work on python lists.

Also, even though this shall not be the part of the question am somewhat curious to learn that if i were to implement the same fucnitonality for one of my class objects how would i do..?

Comment: What happened when you tried reading a Numpy tutorial? It doesn't work with lists because there *isn't anything lists could do* where it would make sense to use `...` in the syntax.

Comment: In `arr[..., ::-1]` the `...` stands for a variable number of ':', hence the last 2 cases just reverse the last dimension.  `arr[...]` is the same as `arr[:]`, a `view` without change.  Lists only have one level of indexing, so `alist[:]` and `alist[::-1]` work, but nothing which a comma, or the `ellipsis`.  Sublists in a nested list have to have their own indexing.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I just didn't find any online resource to look at that definition, And i thought  a google search would bring in results from the official numpy documentation which it did not therefore i asked the question over here.

Comment: And i would like to thank @hpaulj as their answer was satisfactory...But am stil looking for more answers...Let's see in how many more wordful ways the community can explain it for anyone can find anyones answer comprehensible as i found yours.

Comment: " i thought a google search would bring in results from the official numpy documentation which it did not" [First result on Google or DuckDuckGo for `numpy documentation tutorial`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html). Section "Indexing, Slicing and Iterating". Direct explanation: "The dots (...) represent as many colons as needed to produce a complete indexing tuple.", followed by a worked example. What did *you* search for?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel i just searched "What does arr[...] mean for numpy arrays and why doesn't it work for python lists " and i use *bing* as my search engine but i also had the same query on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `arr[..., ::-1]` the `...` stands for a variable number of `:`, hence the last 2 cases just reverse the last dimension.

`arr[...]` is the same as `arr[:]`, a `view` without change.

Lists only have one level of indexing, so `alist[:]` and `alist[::-1]` work, but nothing which a comma, or the ellipsis. Sublists in a nested list have to have their own indexing.

```
alist[:]            # a copy
alist[::-1]         # a reverse copy
```

these also work for strings

```
In [187]: 'astring'[:]
Out[187]: 'astring'
In [188]: 'astring'[::-1]
Out[188]: 'gnirtsa'
```

Basic reference for numpy indexing:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html

a start for python sequence indexing (for lists and strings)

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations

I'm more familiar with `numpy` documentation, since I learned python basics too long ago.  List indexing should be well covered in any Python intro book.